# how I calculate xy coordinates?

Tags: java, polymorphism, abstract, extends

**hello , i'm a new programming student  . 
how can i calculate x&y coordinate ??**

**Q:**  Example: Suppose we create a program that simulates
the movement of several types of animals for a
biological study. Classes Fish, Frog and Bird
represent the three types of animals under
investigation.

 Each class extends superclass Animal, which contains a
method move and maintains an animal’s current location as
x-y coordinates. Each subclass implements method move.

 A program maintains an Animal array containing
references to objects of the various Animal subclasses. To
simulate the animals’ movements, the program sends each
object the same message once per second—namely, move.

 Each specific type of Animal responds to a move
message in a unique way:

 a Fish might swim three feet

 a Frog might jump five feet

 a Bird might fly ten feet.

 The program issues the same message (i.e., move) to each
animal object, but each object knows how to modify its x-y
coordinates appropriately for its specific type of movement.

 Relying on each object to know how to “do the right thing”
in response to the same method call is the key concept of
polymorphism.

 The same message sent to a variety of objects has “many
forms” of results—hence the term polymorphism.

```js
package animals;

public class Animals {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        
        Fish F = new Fish ("fish");
        Frog Fr = new Frog ("frog");
        Bird B = new Bird ("bird");
      
        
       Animal[] A = new Animal [3];
        A[0]= F;
        A[1]=Fr;
        A[2]=B;
        
        for (int i=0 ; i <3; i++){
           A[i].toString();
        }
    }
    
}
```

```js
package animals;

public abstract class Animal {
     private String type;
     
   public Animal (String type){
       this.type = type ;
   }
    
   public abstract int move ();
   
   public String toString (){
       return String.format(type);
   }
    
}
```

```js
package animals;
public class Fish extends Animal {
    public Fish (String name){
        super(name);
    }
    @Override
    public int move () {
   //here what I write ?
}
    @Override
    public String toString (){
       return String.format("Fish swim "+move()+"  feet");
   }}
```

i do all the animals like this ^^

Comment: You say that "... Animal ... which ... maintains an animal’s current location as x-y coordinates.", but I don't see any `x` or `y` reference in the `Animal` class; also "Fish might swim three feet"... this is just a movement constraint; who decides where the fish actually moves? Some AI?

Comment: should be create x and y  reference ? :(   and how can i do the move method ?!

Answer (score 0):

There is a first issue that I see in your design. When you declare a constructor on the specialized class with a type parameter, like you did in your Fish class example:

```
 public Fish (String name){
    super(name);
}
```

This would allow me to create an instance of fish this way:

```
Fish salmon = new Fish("Parot");
```

and this makes no sens though I don't have any compile time or runtime error. Instead you should create the specialized class constructor like this:

```
public Fish (){
    super("Fish");
}
```

This way you are sure the type paramater will really correspond to a fish. Now if you would like to distinguish between the variety of fishes and the variety of birds or frog, etc, I would suggest that you add a subType variable similar to the type and create a second level of specialization of the classes. Example:

```
// 2nd level of inheritance since Parot extents Bird and Bird extends Animal
public class Parot exents Bird {
    public Parot() {
        super ("Parot"); // Parot as a subType and not the type
    }
}
```

Now back to what you were asking, yes you should keep a reference to the x and y position variables and you can do that at the level of the Animal base class. I suggest that you specify x and y as private double, and **then you create public getters for x and y, but protected setters for them, so that they can only be modified inside a specializing class such as Bird, Fish**, ...

Here is how I would modify your base Animal class

```
public abstract class Animal {

    private String type;
    private double x, y;

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    protected void setX(double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    protected void setY(double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Animal (String type){
        this.type = type ;
    }

    public abstract int move ();

    public String toString (){
        return String.format(type);
    }

    public String position() {
        return "[" + x + " , " + y + "]";
    }

}
```

I added the `position()`method in order to obtain a nice display of the x,y position of the animal. To make it more realistic, you may keep the previous position and compute the new position from the old position, but I will leave this add-on to you.

Now here is how I would modify the Fish class. Since, according to your above specifications, a fish move everytime by 3 feet, this information can be stored in a final static variable. Then I can randomly get a value for x and then use mathematical triangle identity to deduce the y value.

```
public class Fish extends Animal {

    public final static int FISH_MOVE_LENGTH = 3;

    public Fish (){
        super("Fish");
    }

    @Override
    public int move () {
        Random r = new Random();
        double xValue = r.nextInt(FISH_MOVE_LENGTH/2)+ 0.0D;
        double yValue = Math.sqrt(FISH_MOVE_LENGTH*FISH_MOVE_LENGTH -     xValue*xValue);
        setX(xValue);
        setY(yValue);

        return (int)Math.sqrt(xValue*xValue + yValue*yValue);

    }

    @Override
    public String toString (){
       return String.format("Fish swim "+move()+"  feet and its current     position is " + position());
    }}
```

I used the same approach for the other specialization class, the only thing that changes between the three class is `public final static int FISH_MOVE_LENGTH = 3`which will change to reflect your above specification for each kind of animal.

I have added a little change also to your Animals class. First to randomly pick up which animal to move and then to move it and display the move informations along with the new position

All I change to the Animals class was to comment your loop

```
//        for (int i=0 ; i <3; i++){
//           A[i].toString();
//        }
```

And replace it by

```
 Random maestro = new Random();
 while (true) {

    int elementToPick = maestro.nextInt(3);
    System.out.println(A[elementToPick]);
    Thread.sleep(500);

 }
```

The Thread.sleep is there for demo purpose, allowing me to elapse some time before the various displays, which otherwise would go too fast.

Here is a sample result

[image: Birds, Frogs and Fishes]